# Unresolved external symbol in c for user-define function

Tags: c, function, unresolved-external

im very new to programming and for my course we learning c language so have mercy on my badly written code and the compiler just wont run the program because of the error so its hard for me to identify whats wrong.Back to main question im getting unresolved external symbol...referenced in function_main and i dont really know where im messed up

```
#include<stdio.h>
char DisplayMenu(void);
void ViewBooks();
void SearchBookPrice();
void UpdateBookPrice();


int main()
{
    char userchoice;
    int bookID[5] = { 200,230,500,540,700 };
    char bookTitle[5][50] = { {"Using Information Technology 12th Edition" }, { "Beyond HTML" },{"Build Your Own PC"},{"Instant Java Servlets"},{"DIgital Image: A Practical Guide"} };
    float bookPrice[5] = { 100.30,50.40,47,83.30,22.90 };

    do
    {
        userchoice = DisplayMenu();
        if (userchoice == 'V')
            ViewBooks();
        else if (userchoice == 'S')
            SearchBookPrice();
        else if (userchoice == 'U')
            UpdateBookPrice();
    } while (userchoice != 'E');

    printf("Thank you for using our system. Have a nice day!\n");

    return 0;
}

char DisplayMenu(void)
{
    char choice;

    printf("*************************************************************************\n");
    printf("V:View Books  S:Search Book Price  U:Update Book Price  E:Exit");
    printf("*************************************************************************\n");
 
    do
    {
        printf("Enter your choice: ");
        scanf(" %c", &choice);

        if (choice != 'V' && choice != 'S' && choice != 'U' && choice != 'E')
            printf("Invalid Choice\n");

    } while (choice != 'V' && choice != 'S' && choice != 'U' && choice != 'E');
    

    return choice;
}

void ViewBooks(int bookID[],float bookPrice[])
{
    printf("%d   Using Information Technology 12th Edition   $%f\n", bookID[0], bookPrice[0]);
    printf("%d   Beyond HTML   $%f\n", bookID[1], bookPrice[1]);
    printf("%d   Build Your Own PC   $%f\n", bookID[2], bookPrice[2]);
    printf("%d   Instant Java Servlets  $%f\n", bookID[3], bookPrice[3]);
    printf("%d   Digital Image: A Pratical Guide  $%f\n", bookID[4], bookPrice[4]);

    return;
}

void SearchBookPrice(int bookID[5],char bookTitle[5][50], float bookPrice[5])
{
    int idsearch, i= 0, match = -1;
    printf("*************************************************************************\n");
    printf("Search by book ID\n");
    printf("*************************************************************************\n");

    printf("Enter book ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &idsearch);

    while (i<5 && match==-1)
    {
        if (bookID[i] == idsearch)
            match = i;
        i++;
    }



    if (match == -1)
        printf("Please refer to the customer service for assitance");
    else
    {
        printf("The book id is : %d\n", &idsearch);
        printf("The price of %s is %f", bookTitle[match], bookPrice[match]);
    }

    return;

}

void UpdateBookPrice(int bookID[5], char bookTitle[5][50], float bookPrice[5])
{
    int idsearch, i = 0, match = -1;
    printf("Enter book ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &idsearch);
    while (i < 5 && match == -1)
    {
        if (bookID[i] == idsearch)
            match = i;
        i++;
    }
    if (match == -1)
        printf("The book ID is not found. Please make sure the book ID is correct");
    else
    {
        printf("Current book price is %f\n", bookPrice[match]);
        printf("Enter new price for (%d-%s): ", bookID[match], bookTitle[match]);
        scanf("%f", &bookPrice[match]);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Post the full error message. You have omitted the most critical info - the symbol name which is unresolved.

Comment: Can't reproduce.  Is the **exact** code you're trying to compile?

Comment: You don't pass any parameters to the functions that are expecting parameters. You could have prevented this on the compiler level by providing proper function prototypes with argument lists.

Comment: Using a C compiler, it compiled just fine for me.  Using C++ compiler, there are unresolved symbols because your forward declarations and calls to `ViewBook`, `SearchBookPrice` and `UpdateBookPrice` don't include the parameters, which are part of the function's signature in C++.  It's trying to call a version taking no parameters, but you've only supplied ones that require parameters.

Comment: @Perette With C its undefined behavior though, as these functions require parameters, but these are not provided.

Comment: If the C compiler isn't warning about the *error* in `printf("The book id is : %d\n", &idsearch);` you should crank up the warning level. The executable code did link, though, without any unresolved external symbol.

Comment: Things could really be simplified if you declared a `struct book { .... };`

Answer (score 0):

Your function declaration is not matched with function body.

This is working code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
char DisplayMenu(void);
void ViewBooks(int bookID[],float bookPrice[]);
void SearchBookPrice(int bookID[5],char bookTitle[5][50], float bookPrice[5]);
void UpdateBookPrice(int bookID[5], char bookTitle[5][50], float bookPrice[5]);


int main()
{
    char userchoice;
    int bookID[5] = { 200,230,500,540,700 };
    char bookTitle[5][50] = { {"Using Information Technology 12th Edition" }, { "Beyond HTML" },{"Build Your Own PC"},{"Instant Java Servlets"},{"DIgital Image: A Practical Guide"} };
    float bookPrice[5] = { 100.30,50.40,47,83.30,22.90 };

    do
    {
        userchoice = DisplayMenu();
        if (userchoice == 'V')
            ViewBooks(bookID, bookPrice);
        else if (userchoice == 'S')
            SearchBookPrice(bookID, bookTitle, bookPrice);
        else if (userchoice == 'U')
            UpdateBookPrice(bookID, bookTitle, bookPrice);
    } while (userchoice != 'E');

    printf("Thank you for using our system. Have a nice day!\n");

    return 0;
}

char DisplayMenu(void)
{
    char choice;

    printf("*************************************************************************\n");
    printf("V:View Books  S:Search Book Price  U:Update Book Price  E:Exit");
    printf("*************************************************************************\n");
 
    do
    {
        printf("Enter your choice: ");
        scanf(" %c", &choice);

        if (choice != 'V' && choice != 'S' && choice != 'U' && choice != 'E')
            printf("Invalid Choice\n");

    } while (choice != 'V' && choice != 'S' && choice != 'U' && choice != 'E');
    

    return choice;
}

void ViewBooks(int bookID[],float bookPrice[])
{
    printf("%d   Using Information Technology 12th Edition   $%f\n", bookID[0], bookPrice[0]);
    printf("%d   Beyond HTML   $%f\n", bookID[1], bookPrice[1]);
    printf("%d   Build Your Own PC   $%f\n", bookID[2], bookPrice[2]);
    printf("%d   Instant Java Servlets  $%f\n", bookID[3], bookPrice[3]);
    printf("%d   Digital Image: A Pratical Guide  $%f\n", bookID[4], bookPrice[4]);

    return;
}

void SearchBookPrice(int bookID[5],char bookTitle[5][50], float bookPrice[5])
{
    int idsearch, i= 0, match = -1;
    printf("*************************************************************************\n");
    printf("Search by book ID\n");
    printf("*************************************************************************\n");

    printf("Enter book ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &idsearch);

    while (i<5 && match==-1)
    {
        if (bookID[i] == idsearch)
            match = i;
        i++;
    }



    if (match == -1)
        printf("Please refer to the customer service for assitance");
    else
    {
        printf("The book id is : %d\n", &idsearch);
        printf("The price of %s is %f", bookTitle[match], bookPrice[match]);
    }

    return;

}

void UpdateBookPrice(int bookID[5], char bookTitle[5][50], float bookPrice[5])
{
    int idsearch, i = 0, match = -1;
    printf("Enter book ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &idsearch);
    while (i < 5 && match == -1)
    {
        if (bookID[i] == idsearch)
            match = i;
        i++;
    }
    if (match == -1)
        printf("The book ID is not found. Please make sure the book ID is correct");
    else
    {
        printf("Current book price is %f\n", bookPrice[match]);
        printf("Enter new price for (%d-%s): ", bookID[match], bookTitle[match]);
        scanf("%f", &bookPrice[match]);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `printf("The book id is : %d\n", &idsearch);` is "working code"?

Comment: apparently it is not working now that i can run the code but fix it by replacing idsearch with bookID[match]

Comment: this answer does not cleanly compile! amongst other things:  "untitled2.c:87:35: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]" and several warnings about value changes because this:  `float bookPrice[5] = { 100.30,50.40,47,83.30,22.90 };` is trying to initialize a `float` array with `double` values.  Note: a float value has trailing `f` like: `100.30f`